# Pandoc version 1.12.3 was not found

Tags: r, centos, rstudio, centos7, pandoc

By using sudo R, I can't find in my shinyApp the pandoc and I get this message.

```
Warning: Error in : pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

When I do:

```
rmarkdown::pandoc_available()
```

I get

```
FALSE
```

When I do:

```
pandoc -v
```

I get

```
pandoc 1.17.2
...
Default user data directory: /home/scenerydev/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2016 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is no warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

But when I do

```
Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO_PANDOC")
```

I get

```
""
```

I don't have Rstudio installed. Do I need to have it installed in order to find the pandoc? I run a Centos 7 x64-bit server and I was hoping I could bypass the rstudio installation, since it does not provide anything to my services. If not, how can I define the env of the pandoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not a straightforward answer, what I ended up doing, was installing rstudio-server instead, so that I can get a much more lightweight solution to solve my problem. I did not find any other way of bypassing this issue. I am open to suggestions if something comes up.